# How to extract model fields from Serializer in DRF?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I need to get model fields list in Django Rest Framework.

i got field list from models by below method,

```
filter_fields = model._meta.get_all_field_names()
```

tried this too,

```
filter_fields = [f.name for f in model._meta.fields]
```

but i want to get it from serializer itself instead extracting from model.

is there a  way to do so?

Comment: You could just do, `[f.name for f in model._meta.fields]`

Comment: i did this ... instead i found an alternate using get_all_field_names() will reduce custom loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a serializer based on `ModerlSerializer` you have to set `model` in `Meta`, so you have direct access to model in there (I think It's a hacky solution, but it works)

```
MySerializer.Meta.model._meta.get_all_field_names()
```

Comment: great .. but after seeing this, getting from model will be better... but great i learned something in this.. i wish to get better method.. like serializer.fields()

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Django 3.1.4 with DRF 3.12.2. It seems `SampleFileSerializer.Meta.fields` worked for me.